# How to visit promises recursively using observables and/or async generators?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs, observable

I've been trying to transverse a tree of promises using async iterators and observables

**Context**

I am using typescript 2.9 and running the program with ts-node

Let's say I have a function fetchData(params) that returns a promise this way

```
async fetchData(params) {
  const fetchedData = wait fetch(...params);
  return {
    nextParams: fetchedData.nextParams,
    nodeData: fetchedData.nodeData
  }
}
```

**The goal**

What I want to do is create an observable that can be subscribed to read each node, each node will contain nodeData. So this leaves to a recursive function that uses fetch

**Workarounds**
One can do a function that, recursively, returns `{ nodeData: ...}` or `{ nodeData: ..., nextParams: ... }`, so the consumer can call await for next

```
async transversePromiseTree(fetchParams) {
  const { nextParams, nodeData } = await fetchData(fetchParams);
  if (nextParams) {
    return {
      nodeData,
      next: transversePromiseTree(nextParams)
    }
  }

  return { nodeData };
}

async function getData(rootFetchParams) {
  let node = await transversePromiseTree(rootFetchParams);
  while (node.next) {
    console.log(node.nodeData);
    node = await node.next
  }
}
```

Until this it works perfectly fine, it outputs something like:

```
... node data ...
*after couple of seconds*
... another node data ...
*after couple of seconds*
... some other nothe data ...
*until it reaches the end of the tree*
```

**Constraints** The program does not know how big is the list or the tree

**The problem** The problem comes when I want to create an async iterable this way, I want to create this iterable in order to convert it to an observable

```
async *transversePromiseTree(fetchParams) {
  const { nextParams, nodeData } = await fetchData(fetchParams);
  yield nodeData;
  yield * transversePromiseTree(nextParams);
}
```

And the consumer of the iterable looks like this:

```
async function getData(rootFetchParams) {
  const nodeTree = await transversePromiseTree(rootFetchParams);
  for await(let nodeData of nodeTree) {
    console.log(nodeData)
  }
}
```

When I run the program I expect to have the exactly same output but I get

```
TypeError: Symbol.asyncIterator is not defined.
```

**The solution I'm trying to find**

The main reason of all of this is just abstract the consumer to an Observable, now my questions:

- Is there a way to create an observable with this behavior without async iterables?
- Is there any solution to the Symbol.asyncIterator not defined error so async iterables are actually usable?

I've been looking in the docs and async generators seem to still under discussion

Any help is well appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `expand` operator of RxJs Observable can help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Symbol.asyncIterator` is not defined in NodeJS context. Therefore you need to define this shim for NodeJS:

```
(Symbol as any).asyncIterator = Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol.for("Symbol.asyncIterator");
```